# ufw status (what does the v6 stand for?)

Tags: ip, tcp, ipv6, ufw

My ufw status output looks like this:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Why did he add the rules twice and what does the v6 stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v6` in your output is short for IPv6.

IPv6 is the new Internet Protocol, which was introduced in 1998 to replace the aging IPv4.